# Join two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join

I  have to tables

**Customer**

```
CustomerID   Name        Surname
---------------------------------
  1          Adam        Test
  2          Robert      Test2
  3          John        Test3
```

**CustomerAddress**

```
CustomerAddressId  CustomerId     AddressId
-------------------------------------------
1                  1              1
2                  1              2
3                  1              3
4                  2              6
5                  2              7
6                  2              8
```

I want to select `CustomerId` from these two tables.

I wrote this query but it multiplies my records.

Comment: What query did you write? It would be helpful for us to have the query, expected output, etc.

Comment: you have 2 proposed answers below check them out and either will get you the non multiplied answers your looking for. @adamek339

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a distinct list of CustomerId from both tables, it'll be easiest to use `UNION`:

```
SELECT CustomerId
FROM Customer
UNION SELECT CustomerId
FROM CustomerAddress
```

Using `UNION ALL` would show duplicates in your result set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DISTINCT` keyword with `JOIN` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.CustomerId     
FROM Customer c INNER JOIIN
     CustomerAddress cs
     ON CD.CustomerId = C.CustomerId;
```

Without `DISTINCT` it would return multiple `CustomerId`s as because of second table has multiple address for same customer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture Customers which has addresses you can use following script :

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customer C
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CustomerAddress CA WHERE C.CustomerId=CA.CustomerId)
```